# Make buttons clean on mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First of all I am a noob of CSS. Also I am using bootstrap framework. I have a question. Recently I created a set of buttons and they are viewable on mobile devices too.

Desktop view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8JCp.png

Mobile view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBPP0.png

So what I want to do is I need to give some small space between rows on mobile device view.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU55k.png

My Code:

```
<?php

include "header.php";
include "navbar.php";
?>

<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">January</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">February</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">March</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">April</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">May</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">June</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">July</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">August</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">September</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">October</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">November</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">December</button>
</div>


<?php
include "footer.php"
?>
```

Anyone help for this? Thanks in Advance. Also sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for that you have to set bottom margin of 5px for all buttons like below

```css
.btn-Margin{
  margin-bottom : 5px
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">January</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">February</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">March</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">April</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">May</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">June</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">July</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">August</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">September</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">October</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">November</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-Margin">December</button>
</div>
```